# To get extended views in XCode?

Tags: xcode

To install command-line tools for XCode requires running

```
xcode-select --install
```

This was not visible in the download tab of the software

[image]

However, I have an intuition that those settings can be extended.
I would definitely like to see all those components possible to install for XCode.

**How can you extend the settings in the XCode GUI?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extend the downloads pane per say, but you can download more tools from the same location by going to **Xcode** → **Open Developer Tool** → **More Developer Tools…**.

Upon logging in with your Developer ID, you can see the [full list of tools](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-), *including the Command Line Tools*.

<sup>I would list them here, but they're behind the developer login so can't be posted publicly.</sup>

---

There are even more Developer downloads, relatively unrelated to Xcode, accessible by removing the `for Xcode -` search criteria:

- https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Comment: Which tools here you need to compile a Linux program to OSX? Thread about it here http://superuser.com/questions/688805/unsupported-architecture-in-installing-linux-program-in-osx

Comment: @Masi Someone's [provided a good answer](http://superuser.com/a/688823/156757) to your question on Super User, and I second it. Try that?